# JSONObject Alternative in Spring and Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I need to pass a map back to the web application.

I'm used to encapsulating the map in a JSONObject

http://json.org/java/

But since I am using Spring and Jackson Haus.

is there an easier way to maintain the pojo? May I can just annotate the MAP ?

Comment: So in your project you have jackson available right... then if you return the map from the controller with @ResponseBody annotation then it will get automatically converted into a json object by spring converters

Comment: I'm returing the map in a POJO using model.addAttribute("pojo", pojo)

Comment: What is "Haus"?

Answer (score 7):

Jackson has `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonNode`, and specific subtypes like `ObjectNode`.
These form so-called `Tree Model`, which is one of 3 ways to handle JSON with Jackson -- some other libraries (like `org.json`) only offer this way.

So you should be able to just use `JsonNode` instead; there is little point in using `org.json` library; it is slow, and has outdated API.

Alternatively you can just use `java.util.Map`, and return that. Jackson can handle standard `List`s, `Map`s and other JDK types just fine.

Comment: I did use map but the object return is not a JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to manipulate the output, ie, you don't want to provide all the fields of the object you can use JSonArray:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
String listUsersJson(ModelMap model) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();
    for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
        JSONObject userJSON = new JSONObject();
        userJSON.put("id", user.getId());
        userJSON.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
        userJSON.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
        userJSON.put("email", user.getEmail());
        userArray.put(userJSON);
    }
    return userArray.toString();
}
```

Use the example from [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON)

Otherwise if you add jackson to your dependencies and set the controller method anotatted with `@ResponseBody` the response will automatically mapped to JSON. Check [here](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-return-json-using-responseboyd/) for a simple example.

Comment: pardon me but if it is a submit request(don't know the actual term) .. it won't forward me to another page.