# No Converter for return type JSONObject

Tags: java, spring-mvc, json

I am using spring mvc and here is my service.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/data/{id}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject data(@PathVariable Long id ,@RequestBody Long Intake ) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("test", false);
            System.out.equals(obj);
            return obj;
    }
```

and it is throwing the error as:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject
```

I have checked many links pointing me that may be the  getter/setter are missing or the @ResponseBody annotation is missing.so I ran this code without the need of getter/setter but still showing me this error.

i have imported this dependency too.

```
import org.json.*;
```

Any thoughts over this issue??

Comment: You can return String from method `obj.toString()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972013/jsonobject-alternative-in-spring-and-jackson

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380913/spring-restful-webservice-returning-json-without-model-object

I have posted there an answer that will also satisfy your needs.

Comment: @VladBochenin `toString()` is a little barbaric, because it slightly gets around Jackson's helpful algorithms and settings. I'm not also sure whether the "Response-Type" will be set to "application/json" after returning a bare String, needs to be checked. `toMap()` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try add jackson in your project (if not declared yet).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or 2 - return String with ObjectMapper serialization.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data/{id}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String data(@PathVariable Long id ,@RequestBody Long Intake ) {
    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

    Map<String, Object> map =  new HashMap<>();
    map.put("test", false);

    return obj.writeValueAsString(map);
}
```

Comment: 1-jackson is added and declared too.2-this is not working.giving "Unhandled exception type JsonProcessingException" at obj.writeValueAsString(map);

Comment: BTW i dont want to return string.i need json object to return

Comment: Did you try it?


 @RequestMapping(value="/data/{id}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String data(@PathVariable Long id ,@RequestBody Long Intake ) {
  try {
      ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
         obj.put("test", false);
         System.out.equals(obj);
             
      return obj.writeValueAsString(obj);   
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   // TODO
  }
 }

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper["factory"]->com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingJsonFactory["codec"]                this is the error.

Comment: The way I know to return o object JSON is with HashMap. because your dynamically structure. I don't know another solution.

Comment: thanx for ur time.i was able to try some more solution but my prblm still exists.